# doctrine2 jointable annotation error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to make a join table from 2 entities with a manytomany relationship like this:

```
class Entity1
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Orders")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_orders",
     *   joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
     */
    private $orders;
}
```

but each time I try to generate the getters and setters I have the same error:

> The annotation @JoinTable... was never imported. Did you forget to add a use statement for this annotation?

So how can I add the use statement? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

Add ORM in front of `JoinTable` and `JoinColumn`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Orders")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_orders",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
 */
```

And add the 'use'-statement at the top of your class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

Comment: @Paul Edited my answer!

Comment: It works now but I want to have a join table with 3 different foreign keys. How can I do that?

Comment: Please don't ask many questions in one. And don't forget to mark the question as answered when is it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `@ORM\` in front of all of your Doctrine annotations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Orders")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_orders",
 *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
 */
private $orders;
```

Comment: I already tried that but I get the same error for the same property

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, I answered to quickly. I didn't see the  '@ORM\JoinColumn'. It works. Thank you.